# Excel Macro (VBA) Image upload to Internet Explorer with Open Twebst

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-11, browser-automation

I've successfully automatized a process with Open Twebst. (Go through some links, fill the forms and upload images..) So, it helped me to upload images to a HTML page in Internet Explorer 10.

I've just changed my laptop and It has Windows 10 (64bit) and it enables to use only Internet Explorer 11 instead of 10. - Previously the macro was running on Win7 - excel 2013 and IE10 - it was worked perfectly.

Somehow the macro stops when the upload browser window appears. I've already installed the program and added its reference in VBA but I had no luck. I was trying to simulate IE10 but it didn't work. I was also trying to do it in Excel 2013 instead of 2016 but it was the same.

Could someone help me to solve this issue? I searched a lot in this topic and as I can see everyone has the same issue: the VBA can't be able to control that window on his own.

This link contains a tutorial for the method I used:
http://codecentrix.blogspot.com/2009/11/automate-html-file-upload-control.html

HTML tag where I upload: ....input type="file"....

I was trying to modify the security settings in IE11, but it wasn't helped me - I'm not an expert in IE, maybe someone knows how to set it.

I would really appreciate any ideas/ codes.
Many thanks!
Zoltán Báthori

Comment: Please include your code and indicate on which line there is a problem and what that problem is. [MCVE] Note that for debugging help we have to be able to reproduce your problem generally speaking.